# Python joining many dataframes using duration match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many data frames staked in a list. Data in each dataframes occurs every 30 minutes at distinctive times. I want to join them using a duration match. An example is given below:

```
biglist3 = [df1,df2,df3] # actually up to df26

df1 = 
index                     S1POA
2019-01-09 13:20:17     742.961815
2019-01-09 14:00:17     791.852790
2019-01-09 14:40:17     794.034572

df2 = 
index                     S2POA
2019-01-09 13:20:32     734.330740
2019-01-09 14:00:32     803.439840
2019-01-09 14:40:32     804.677047

df3 = 
index                     S3POA
2019-01-09 13:20:47     725.699665
2019-01-09 14:00:47     815.026890
2019-01-09 14:40:47     815.319522
```

I would like to combine them into one data frame using duration match. Because row to row time difference is 30 min and different data frames have unique timestamps. 
**My present code is:**

```
l = []
s1 = []
for i in range(0,len(biglist3),1):
    if i==0:
        s1 = biglist3[i]
        l.append(s1)
    else:             #  
        l.append(pd.merge_asof(s1,biglist3[i],left_index=True,right_index=True,direction='nearest'))
combdf = pd.concat(l,0) # combined dataframe
```

**My present output is :**

cmbdf =

```
index                     S1POA           S2POA          S1POA        S3POA
2019-01-09 13:20:17     742.961815     734.330740     742.961815     725.699665
2019-01-09 14:00:17     791.852790     803.439840     791.852790     815.026890
2019-01-09 14:40:17     794.034572     804.677047     794.034572     815.319522
```

My present output looks good but the only problem is the reoccurrence of S1POA each time a new column is added from different data frame.

**My expected output:**

cmbdf =

```
index                     S1POA          S2POA        S3POA
2019-01-09 13:20:17     742.961815     734.330740     725.699665
2019-01-09 14:00:17     791.852790     803.439840     815.026890
2019-01-09 14:40:17     794.034572     804.677047     815.319522
```

What to change in my code so that S1POA does not repeat?

Comment: The index doesn't match between your individual `df` dataframes. How close do the timestamps have to be for data to be in the same row? Would truncating to the minute or 20-min work?

Comment: @busybear The present code is intelligently combining them into a single row. It is good and I have no problem with it. The only problem is reptition of S1POA many times.

Comment: I was going to suggest using `pivot_table` instead. But you would have to match the timestamps by rounding or some other method.

Comment: On some days it maybe 30 or 40 min. Moreover, they don't occur at the same time on different days.

Comment: since you have no problem with he existing code can you try: `combdf.groupby(combdf.columns,axis=1,sort=False).first()`

Comment: @anky_91 Yes! your code removes repeating columns. I have to put one additional line. Instead, Can I do some changes in my code to stop repeatition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have tried something like:

```
final = pd.concat(biglist3,sort=False)
final.groupby(final.index.floor('30min')).first()
```

---

```
                          S1POA       S2POA       S3POA
index                                                  
2019-01-09 13:00:00  742.961815  734.330740  725.699665
2019-01-09 14:00:00  791.852790  803.439840  815.026890
2019-01-09 14:30:00  794.034572  804.677047  815.319522
```

however with your code, you can do:

```
l = []
s1 = []
for i in range(0,len(biglist3),1):
    if i==0:
        s1 = biglist3[i]
        l.append(s1)
    else:             #  
        l.append(pd.merge_asof(s1,biglist3[i],left_index=True,right_index=True,direction='nearest'))
combdf = pd.concat(l,1) # combined dataframe
combdf.groupby(combdf.columns,axis=1,sort=False).first()
```

---

```
                          S1POA       S2POA       S3POA
index                                                  
2019-01-09 13:20:17  742.961815  734.330740  725.699665
2019-01-09 14:00:17  791.852790  803.439840  815.026890
2019-01-09 14:40:17  794.034572  804.677047  815.319522
```

Comment: `pd.concat(l,1)` how does `1` impacts here. Because I have `0` in my code.

Comment: @Mainland with `0` I am  getting a totally different output than what you have showed

Comment: Though I am not able to change my code to stop repeatition but I still take your one line code to remove the repeating columns. Thanks